# How to define a list of functions of the same arity in Scala?

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

In the various Lisps, it's possible for me to create a sequence of functions as if they'd just been normal values:

```lisp
(def ops [+ - * /])
```

Which I can then iterate through, again, as if they were just normal values:

```
(doseq [op ops] // (doseq (op ops) is like for (op <- ops) in scala
  (println (op 1 2 3 4)))
```

Now, I've tried a few things in Scala, all of them failing:

```
scala> List(+, -, *, /)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       List(+, -, *, /)
             ^

scala> List[Double => Double](+, -, *, /)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       List[Double => Double](+, -, *, /)
                               ^

scala> List[Double => Double](+_, -_, *_, /_)
<console>:8: error: not found: value *
              List[Double => Double](+_, -_, *_, /_)
                                             ^
<console>:8: error: not found: value /
              List[Double => Double](+_, -_, *_, /_)
                                                 ^
```

So what's the correct procedure of defining a list of functions/operators in Scala?

Comment: There are good answers below, but, as you can see, you can define in a such way only *same typed* functions. If you want to store different typed functions you have to use *heterogeneous* structures (list for example).

Comment: @DaunnC would you mind elaborating on the use of *use heterogeneous structures* in another answer to the question? I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that these functions are binary operators, i.e., they take *two* operands and return one. So you have to use:

```
List[(Double, Double) => Double](_ + _, _ - _, _ * _, _ / _)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Scala, most value-level operators are actually unary instance methods (maybe all are, not sure if there are counterexmaples). So when you talk about, say, addition of two values of type `Double`, you're really referring to [a method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Double@+%28x:Double%29:Double) of the first value that takes the second value as a parameter. The familiar infix operator syntax [is just sugar](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/118). In other words,

```
scala> 5.7 + 6.3
res0: Double = 12.0
```

is really just a nice shorthand for:

```
scala> 5.7.+(6.3)
res1: Double = 12.0
```

[As @bluenote10 already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26190822/1305344), you can capture these operators by creating anonymous function that take both the first instance and its operand as parameters and returns the result of the `+` method:

```
scala> (lhs: Double, rhs: Double) => lhs + rhs
res2: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>
```

Or as in @bluenote10's example, if the type can be inferred (like in a list with the type provided), you can use the nice underscore syntax:

```
scala> val doublePlus: (Double, Double) => Double = _ + _
doublePlus: (Double, Double) => Double = <function2>
```